# how to subtract a number on the second button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
 function createElement(){
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = input.value;
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = "add 2";
  li.appendChild(div);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  
  btn.onclick = () => {
    let num = parseInt(div.innerText);
    num = num + 2;
    const roundednum = num.toFixed(2);
    div.innerText = roundednum;
    btnCLicked = true;
  }
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", createElement);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

i have this simple code above that creates some elements, and it will add 2 to the number in the div when button inside the `<li>` is clicked, which works perfectly

now i want to subtract 2 from the number when button is clicked the second time, so first click will add 2, second click will subtract 2

so i come up with this code which uses a boolean to add and subtract the number which works

```js
let btnCLicked = false;
function createElement(){
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = input.value;
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = "add 2";
  li.appendChild(div);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  
  btn.onclick = () => {
  if (btnCLicked === false) {
    let num = parseInt(div.innerText);
    num = num + 2;
    const roundednum = num.toFixed(2);
    div.innerText = roundednum;
    btnCLicked = true;
  }else if (btnCLicked === true) {
    let num = parseInt(div.innerText);
    num = num - 2;
    const roundednum = num.toFixed(2);
    div.innerText = roundednum;
    btnCLicked = false;
  }
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", createElement);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

but now the problem  is that when i create an `<li>`, and click the button inside to add 2 to the number, `btnClicked` is now set to `true`.

so when i create another element and click the button for the first time it will subtract the number because `btnClicked` is `true`, which is what i dont want, i want the first click to add and subtract on the second click

how do i solve that problem? im thinking about something like making the boolean only inside each `li` so each `li` has an own boolean and it will not effect other elements but idk lol i have no other idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `let btnCLicked = false;` into the function. Each invocation of `createElement() will create a [`closure`][1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) since it's child function (click handler) is using variables from parents scope:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const ul = document.getElementById("ul");

function createElement() {
  let btnCLicked = false;
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const btn = document.createElement("button");

  div.innerText = input.value || 0;
  btn.innerText = "add 2";

  li.appendChild(div);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  btn.onclick = () => {
    let num = Number(div.innerText);
    if (btnCLicked === false) {
      num += 2;
    } else {
      num -= 2;
    }
    div.innerText = num;
    btnCLicked = !btnCLicked;
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", createElement);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

Comment: oh wow its actually so simple, why does it solve the problem? does it make the boolean only inside each `li` so each `li` has an own boolean and it will not effect other elements?

Comment: @coder read this :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures  (don't skip, it's an important concept in js)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and use a `data-attribute` to track the last action (add or subtract):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function createElement() {
  document.querySelector("#ul").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <li>
      <div>${(+document.querySelector("#input").value).toFixed(2)}</div>
      <button data-action="add">2</button>
    </li>`);
}

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.id === "btn") {
    return createElement();
  }
  if (origin.dataset.action) {
    return addOrSubtract2(origin);
  }
}

function addOrSubtract2(fromBttn) {
  const parentLi = fromBttn.closest("li");
  const add = fromBttn.dataset.action === "add";
  const num = +(parentLi.querySelector("div").textContent) + (add ? 2 : -2);
  fromBttn.dataset.action = add ? "subtract" : "add";
  parentLi.querySelector("div").textContent = num.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
[data-action]:before {
  content: attr(data-action)' ';
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" value=0 step="0.1">
<button id="btn">create new</button>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```